How to write back data into same row last column in same Excel where it read the data?
`I am reading each row from Excel as Hashmap to pass the data to my Automation script, it reads, and completes . I get a Ticket no which I want to write back to the Excel in the same row , last column. So that I can process the data for he next step.
My Excel :



Testcases
Name1
Age1
City1
City2
Ticket No




TC1
John
34
Mumbai
Chennai



TC2
Philips
35
Hyderabad
Mumbai



TC3
Sarah
20
New Delhi
Kolkata



TC4
Peter
27
Chennai
New Delhi




My Expectation :



Testcases
Name1
Age1
City1
City2
Ticket No




TC1
John
34
Mumbai
Chennai
M89373


TC2
Philips
35
Hyderabad
Mumbai
H15243


TC3
Sarah
20
New Delhi
Kolkata
H89734


TC4
Peter
27
Chennai
New Delhi
KT98273



I have Excel Reader Utility from where my data gets read. But writing back to the same excel sheet in same row from where it read the same is challenging.
Giving a short code extract of Excel Reader :
My Data provider
@DataProvider(name = "Test1")
     public static Object[][] getDetails() {
        ExcelReaderUtil excelReaderUtil = new ExcelReaderUtil("InputData1.xlsx");
        return excelReaderUtil.getFilteredDataAsHashMapFromSheet("Test1", "SheetName1");

    }

My Excel Reader Utility

 public ExcelReaderUtil(String excelfilePath) {
        try {
            this.file = new File(excelfilePath);
            if (!this.file.exists()) {
                this.file = new File(Constants.WORKING_DIRECTORY + "/" + excelfilePath);
                if (!this.file.exists()) {
                    this.file = new File(Constants.WORKING_DIRECTORY + "/src/test/resources/data/" + excelfilePath);
                }
            }

            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(this.file);
            this.work_book = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
        } catch (Exception var3) {
            LoggerUtil.log(var3.getMessage());
        }

    }


  public Object[][] getFilteredDataAsHashMapFromSheet(String sheetName, String testCaseName) {
        XSSFSheet sheet = this.work_book.getSheet(sheetName);
        Object[][] dataArray = this.getDataAsHashMapFromSheet(sheet);
        return this.getFilteredDataAsHashMapFromSheet(dataArray, testCaseName);
    }


To Write back ..
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception  {
        XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet spreadsheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);
        FileOutputStream fos=null;
        
            Row row=spreadsheet.createRow(i);
                Cell value=row.createCell(j);
                value.setCellValue(ticketno);
                fos=new FileOutputStream("InputData1.xlsx");
                wb.write(fos);
            
         wb.close();
        fos.close();
    }


Confusing. You have a custom class to read, but it doesn't write - why?

when you read each row from the excel and populate the object array, also store the  rowIndex in the hasMap, so next time you write the last column, you know which row to write to

@Hendra, Thank You . I had Testcase name in each row like TC01, TC02 etc.. so extracted the numeric part to write back into it. Thanks for the idea.
